# How can I keep map labels under a Polygon in Google Maps SDK for IOS?

Tags: polygon, google-polyline, gmsmapview

Is there any way to keep the map labels with street names and POIs under GMSOverlays like GMSPolygons and GMSPolylines?

I have tried with different Zindex but to no vail.

This is what I get:

[image]

But as the polygon is the important thing here, I don't want the map labels on top of it, because they are, in my case, irrelevant. Besides I use a semitransparent fill color and you can still see the street names through it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The only way I found was to add a Tile layer on top of the mapView like this:

```
mapView.mapType = .none // Set the map type to .none, as it will not be visible
    
let urls: GMSTileURLConstructor = { (x, y, zoom) in
    let url = "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x=\(x)&y=\(y)&z=\(zoom)&scale=2"
    return URL(string: url)
}
let layer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: urls)
layer.tileSize = 1024 // To get bigger fonts in mobile device with high resollution
layer.map = mapView
```

The only drawback is that when the map is rotated the labels are rotated too as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]